Open gedit in VNC session but pop up on Local Computer
In VNC session, I'm trying to run/open gedit in terminal but gedit is not pop up, the gedit is showing in real local desktop. Does anyone know how to make the gedit showing in my VNC session instead of real local desktop?
My VNC session start process is, login local host PC(Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) first, then I go back to my Win10 laptop then SSH to Ubuntu to enable VNC port by following command and VNC session is working fine. By the way, I used tigervnc to launch vncserver.
vncserver :2 -geometry 1920x1200 -localhost no
Not sure if my xstart setting is wrong to make this stranger.
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:GNOME"
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources

#dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session

gnome-session --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check

